# C# Console application properties.resources isn't working? What reference can I use to fix this?

Tags: c#

so I'm basically making a program and it needs to pull a file from it's resources, I'm using

```
 WriteFileToPath(ConsoleApplication2.Properties.Resources.raw, Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\" + FileName + ".exe");
```

But actually getting the error: `Error  1   The type or namespace name 'Properties' does not exist in the namespace 'ConsoleApplication2' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  c:\users\sand n\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs    31`

What reference can I use to fix this, I know it can be done for a fact because my friend's actually doing the same thing.

Comment: What is the build action for the Resources.resx file? Make sure it's ResXFileCodeGenerator

Comment: @ThomasLevesque The resources file is a executable exe file.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I added the file as "Add new existing file", am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :** you are are adding the `resource`(in your case `exe` file) as a normal `project file` using `Add Existing file` option.

**Solution :**  you should add the `Resource`(in your case `exe` file) using `Resources tab` from the project `properties` window.

Try This:

1.Right click on `project` and goto `Properties`.
2.Goto `Resources` tab.
3.click on `Add Resource` dropdown menu on top.
4.Select `Add Exisiting FIle...`.
5.Select the `exe file` you want to add.

Now from program try to access as below:

```
<ApplicationName>.Properties.Resources.<FileName>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe I forgot about this haha.